# What consumes less memory an actual image or a drawn image?

Tags: ios, image, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I am designing an app and I am creating some images with [PaintCode](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/).

Using that program I get the actual code for each image that I create, thus allowing me to choose to insert code or use an actual image. I was wondering what would consume less memory, the image code or an actual PNG?

I know an image memory consumption is `width x height x 4 = bytes in memory` but I have no idea whether an image that is generated by code is more memory efficient, less memory efficient or breaks even?

This decision is particularly important given the different screen resolutions. its a lot easier to create an image in code and expand it to whatever size I want rather than go to Photoshop every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer varies from other answers because I have the impression the graphics context is your most common destination -- that you are not always rendering to a discrete bitmap. So for the purposes of typical drawing:

> I was wondering what would consume less memory, the image code or an actual PNG?

It's most likely that the code will result in far less memory consumption.

> I have no idea whether an image that is generated by code is more memory efficient, less memory efficient or breaks even?

There are a lot of variables and there is no simple equation to tell you which is better for any given input. If it's simple enough to create with a WYSIWYG, it's likely much smaller as code.

If you need to create intermediate rasterizations or layers for a vector based renderer, then memory will be about equal once you have added the first layer. Typically, one does/should not render each view or layer (not CALayer, btw) to these intermediates and instead **render directly into the graphics context**. When all your views render directly into the graphics context, they write to the same destination.

With code, you also open yourself to a few other variables which have the potential to add a lot of memory. The effects of font loading and caching can be quite high, and the code generator you use is not going to examine how you could achieve the best caching and sharing of these resources if you find you need to minimize memory consumption.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to draw images, you should try to use `UIImageView` if you possibly can. It's generally the fastest and cheapest way to get an image to the screen, and it's reasonably flexible.

someone explaind it better here.
[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827990/uiimageview-vs-uiview-w-image-efficiency)

Answer (score 0):

A vector image is almost always smaller in storage than it's raster counterpart, except for photographs. In memory though, they both have to be rasterized if you need to display them, so they will use more or less the same the same amount of memory.

However, I am highly skeptical of the usefulness of PaintCode; in general it's better to use a standard image format such as .svg or .eps, instead of non standard format such as a domain specific language (DSL) within Objective C.

Comment: Your answer regarding vector versus raster is correct, however PaintCode does generate Objective C code. PaintCode can import SVG and PSD files (both standard formats), as well as using their built-in drawing features. See the link to PaintCode from the OP for more info.

Answer (score -3):

It makes no difference at all, provided the final image size (in point dimensions) is the same as the display size (in point dimensions). What is ultimately displayed in your app is, say, a 100x100 bitmap. Those are the same number of bits no matter how they were obtained to start with.

The place where memory gets wasted is from holding on to an image that is much larger (in point dimensions) than it is actually being displayed in the interface.

If I load a 3MB PNG from my app bundle, scale it down to 100x100, and draw it in the interface, and let go of the original 3MB PNG, the result is *exactly* the same amount of memory in the backing store as if I draw the content of a 100X100 graphics context from scratch myself using Core Graphics (which is what PaintCode helps you do).

Comment: It does make a difference (obviously) in how much memory that the app takes up on the device.  If you draw it in code, it will be far smaller than if you save different resolutions as part of your app bundle.  Once you load it into RAM however, as you discuss here, there won't be any difference.

Comment: I can see it as being considerably more than just a crutch. If your designer wants to create any kind of sophisticated imagery that needs to be generated dynamically, any non-uniform shape (e.g. a human figure or a logo) will be easier for them to draw in PaintCode than for you to create programmatically by hand.